# How do I use bootstrap-sass's autoprefixer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass, autoprefixer

I have a Rails app where I’m using  the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#sass-autoprefixer) gem which lists [autoprefixer-rails](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails) as a dependency.

I don’t quite understand how to get Autoprefixer to prefix my app’s CSS. Do I need some asset config? Will it prefix compiled Sass in dev while in asset debug mode?

According to autoprefixer-rails’s docs, I just have to clear my cache and write CSS... None of my compiled Sass has any prefixes, but Bootstrap’s CSS does.

Any help/explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is found to be simple
Add the autoprefixer-rails gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
# In gemfile
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

# Install the gem
$ bundle install
```

Clear your cache:

```
# Its very important
$ rake tmp:clear
```

Although the gem `autoprefixer-rails` is a dependency to `bootstrap-rails` it looks like it uses the `autoprefixer-rails` internally and the `sprockets` has no idea about it.

Add your css styles without browser prefixes in `.css`, `.scss`, or `.sass` file. Then you find that your style have prefix added.
 If you have

```
.fullscreen a {
    display: flex;
}
```

you will get

```
.fullscreen a {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I need to add it to my Gemfile because it's already a dependency of `bootstrap-sass` which is in my Gemfile. I can see it when I `bundle list`. I've tried clearing my cache, but I'm still not seeing prefixes added to the compiled CSS.

Comment: try restarting your `rails-server` and if not fixed, try including it in `gemfile` and restarting the `app` again.. try hard-reloading the browser

Comment: I have edited the Answer @TracyFu, if any problem lets communicate

Comment: Meh. I think you're right. It only works if I explicitly add it to the Gemfile. Thanks for your help.